# What is the difference between resource and category of DBpedia

Tags: uses-of-open-data, linked-data, rdf, dbpedia

My initial understanding of DBpedia was that `resources` are lower level entities and `categories` are higher level entities. Since categories are higher level, I thought that they do not have a corresponding `resource` page.

However, today I realised that every entity in DBpedia has a `resource` page. However, now I am not clear why `category` pages are there when every DBpedia entity has a `resource` page.

- Example of a `resource`: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Support_vector_machine
- Example of a `category`: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Support_vector_machines

My question is, what is the difference between `resource` and `category` in DBpedia?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Can you please include example URIs (for `category` and `resource`)?

Comment: @unor edited the question :)

Comment: companion to wikipedia category